# Random float in open interval

Tags: ruby, random

So I want to generate a random float in Ruby which lies in the interval `(0.0, 1.0)`. Obviously, if we were talking about a closed interval, this would be totally straightforward:

```
Random.rand
```

...*but* we are talking about the *open* interval, i.e. the number must never be exactly 0.0 or 1.0 because this would crash the program. Just to give a little background, the random float serves as an input to a statistical function which throws an error if the input is not in `(0.0, 1.0)`.

I can think of obvious solutions, such as "rolling again" if the result is 0.0 or 1.0, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is the best that can be done

```
Random.rand(Float::MIN...1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
rand(Float::MIN..1-Float::MIN)
```